# What will be the closed formula for the following recursive function?

Tags: closed-form, recursion

What will be the closed formula for the following recursive function?

> F(n) = F(n/2) +1 if n is even
>
> F(n) = F(n-1) + 1 if n is odd
>
> F(1) = 0

How do we generate closed formula for such recursive functions?

Thanks.

Comment: This is twice the number of ones in the binary expansion of n, plus the number of zeroes, minus two. How to find this? Looking at small cases and twiddling.

Comment: OEIS entry [A014701](https://oeis.org/A014701).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

> $\large\tt Hint:$

$\ds{{\cal F}\pars{z} \equiv \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\rm F}\pars{n}\,z^{n}\,,\qquad
z \in {\mathbb Z}\,,\quad\verts{z} < 1}$.

> \begin{align}
> {\cal F}\pars{z}
> &=
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\rm F}\pars{2n + 1}\,z^{2n + 1}
> +
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\rm F}\pars{2n + 2}\,z^{2n + 2}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {\rm F}\pars{1}z + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{{\rm F}\pars{2n} + 1}\,z^{2n + 1}
> +
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\rm F}\pars{2n + 2}\,z^{2n + 2}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{\rm F}\pars{2n + 2} + 1}\,z^{2n + 3}
> +
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\rm F}\pars{2n + 2}\,z^{2n + 2}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \pars{z + 1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\rm F}\pars{2n + 2}\,z^{2n + 2}
> +
> {z^{3} \over 1 - z^{2}}
> =
> \pars{z + 1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{\rm F}\pars{n + 1} + 1}\,z^{2n + 2}
> +
> {z^{3} \over 1 - z^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \pars{z + 1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\rm F}\pars{n}\,z^{2n}
> +
> \pars{z + 1}\,{z^{2} \over 1 - z^{2}}
> +
> {z^{3} \over 1 - z^{2}}
> \end{align}

$$
{\cal F}\pars{z}
=
\pars{z + 1}{\cal F}\pars{z^{2}}
+
{z^{2} \over 1 - z}
+
{z^{3} \over 1 - z^{2}}
$$